# when we have multi despatches on a single action creator, what is the exact life cycle of the whole app?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am using, React Native, Redux and Thunk. In one of my action creators called `loginUser` I have two despatches, like below:

```
export const loginUser = (email, password) => {
   return (dispatch) => {
      console.log(1);
      dispatch({ type: 'show_spinner', payload: true });
      console.log(2);
      firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(user => {
         dispatch({ type: 'success', payload: user });
       })          
      console.log(3);
  };
};
```

and I have this class based component below:

```
class LoginForm extends Component {
  logUser() {
    this.props.loginUser('test@test.com', 'myPassword');
  }

  renderButton() {
    console.log('renderButton');
    if (!this.props.show_spinner) {
        return (

              <Button
                onPress={this.logUser.bind(this)}
                title='clicl here'
              >              
      );
    }    
    return (
         <Text>please wait</Text>
    );
  }

  render() {  
    console.log('render');
    return (  
       <View style={blabla}>
          {this.renderButton()}
       </View>
    );
  }
}
```

when I click on the button, what I expect is that it calls the action creator `loginUser`. than I see `1` and console and then it dispatches that `show-spinner` and it goes to render the `LoginForm` component so i see `render` on the console and `renderButton` and then it comes back to the action creator `loginUser` to go through the rest of the code lines, so i see `2` and `3`.

but what happens is that I see:
`1`
`2`
`3`
`render`
`renderButton`

so long story short, when we have multi despatches on a single action creator, what is the exact life cycle of the whole app?

Comment: Are you asking to learn or to fix the problem? To learn the lifecycle, I think it really depends on how the control flows for each and every app. To fix _your_ problem, I think you need your whole function to be `async` and then `await` on your `despatch()`s

Comment: @KhalilKhalaf  I need to know what is happening, this code already do what i want but i like to know why the console logs are called that way

Comment: Because the block of code executes without waiting in any statement, so despite if promises (the 'then') are done and ready, the console.logs get hits anyway; but _then_ the despatches finish and get ready and etc

Comment: @KhalilKhalaf thanks please add more details and add it as an asnwer

Comment: my main question is that why it comes back to action-creator's rest of the lines before it renders the component that the first dispatch in the action-creator targeted?